# Heroku Push Failing: "undefined method"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cloud9-ide

Hey I'm having some trouble pushing my rails project out to heroku, i'm getting the follow error:

```
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        I, [2015-07-24T19:05:36.903629 #973]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/public/assets/application-3dba84f3550d057a7ebd21940bb94ece39b0ea686486aaaf4c32bb2fda950496.js
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:266:in `sprockets_context'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:112:in `asset_path'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:188:in `font_path'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:140:in `_perform'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/script/tree/node.rb:50:in `perform'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:402:in `visit_return'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:8:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:248:in `block (3 levels) in perform_sass_fn'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:248:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:248:in `block (2 levels) in perform_sass_fn'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:247:in `catch'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:247:in `block in perform_sass_fn'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:84:in `perform_arguments'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:244:in `perform_sass_fn'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:131:in `_perform'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/script/tree/node.rb:50:in `perform'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/script/tree/operation.rb:64:in `_perform'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/script/tree/node.rb:50:in `perform'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:468:in `visit_variable'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:325:in `block (2 levels) in visit_import'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:325:in `map'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:325:in `block in visit_import'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:88:in `block in with_import'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:88:in `with_import'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:322:in `visit_import'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:325:in `block (2 levels) in visit_import'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:325:in `map'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:325:in `block in visit_import'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:88:in `block in with_import'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:88:in `with_import'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:322:in `visit_import'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `block in visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `map'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:167:in `block in visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:179:in `with_environment'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:166:in `visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `block in visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:186:in `visit_root'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:157:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:8:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in `css_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/engine.rb:278:in `render'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:48:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:86:in `load_asset_by_uri'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:45:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:155:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:38:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:63:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:70:in `find_all_linked_assets'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:138:in `block in find'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:223:in `block in stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:207:in `block in stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:204:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:204:in `stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:222:in `stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:136:in `find'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:162:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:70:in `block (3 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
remote:        /tmp/build_9e450c140b29b08f655c356ad7f8fe81/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:
```

Tt seems to be something to do with js files. I'm using cloud 9 if it's any help.

My gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',        '4.2.2'
gem 'bcrypt',               '3.1.7'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',       '3.2.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.2'
gem 'uglifier',     '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'turbolinks',   '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',         '0.4.0', group: :doc


group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

my application.js file:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

I was previously having problems with the database while trying to push to heroku and I changed my database.yml file to the following if its relevant:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: treebook
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've been unable to solve this for the past few days.

the github repo for the project: https://github.com/Ghrehh/sitenew

edit:

```
I, [2015-07-25T09:07:44.231727 #10217]  INFO -- : Writing /home/ubuntu/workspace/sitenew/public/assets/application-3dba84f3550d057a7ebd21940bb94ece39b0ea686486aaaf4c32bb2fda950496.js
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:266:in `sprockets_context'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:112:in `asset_path'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:188:in `font_path'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:140:in `_perform'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/script/tree/node.rb:50:in `perform'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:402:in `visit_return'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:8:in `visit'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:248:in `block (3 levels) in perform_sass_fn'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:248:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:248:in `block (2 levels) in perform_sass_fn'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:247:in `catch'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:247:in `block in perform_sass_fn'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:84:in `perform_arguments'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:244:in `perform_sass_fn'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:131:in `_perform'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/script/tree/node.rb:50:in `perform'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/script/tree/operation.rb:64:in `_perform'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/script/tree/node.rb:50:in `perform'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:468:in `visit_variable'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:325:in `block (2 levels) in visit_import'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:325:in `map'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:325:in `block in visit_import'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:88:in `block in with_import'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:88:in `with_import'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:322:in `visit_import'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:325:in `block (2 levels) in visit_import'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:325:in `map'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:325:in `block in visit_import'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:88:in `block in with_import'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:88:in `with_import'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:322:in `visit_import'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `block in visit_children'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `map'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `visit_children'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:167:in `block in visit_children'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:179:in `with_environment'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:166:in `visit_children'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `block in visit'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:186:in `visit_root'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:157:in `visit'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:8:in `visit'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in `css_tree'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sass-3.4.16/lib/sass/engine.rb:278:in `render'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:48:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:86:in `load_asset_by_uri'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:45:in `block in load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:155:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:38:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:63:in `find_asset'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:70:in `find_all_linked_assets'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:138:in `block in find'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:223:in `block in stat_tree'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:207:in `block in stat_directory'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:204:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:204:in `stat_directory'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:222:in `stat_tree'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-
```

Comment: Try `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` you might able to spot the issue.  Heroku will reject the `database.yml` file so it's not relevant.

Comment: I tried that and got (I think) the same error message, I appended it to the main post.

Comment: Yes you should get the same error. Since you have require_tree you can start removing the doubtful assets and try to precompile.

Comment: I meant to say try `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` locally not on Heroku.

Comment: How do I go about removing the assets? Also any ideas what's caused this in the first place?

Comment: I am guessing one of your JS files is causing trouble in compilation.

Comment: Solved it! I was linking to a non-existent file in my CSS file, was a stupid mistake. Thanks for your help.

Comment: great! we all make mistakes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was linking to a file that didn't exist in my CSS file, stupid mistake. Don't blindly copy and paste files from previous projects!